# Can't instantiate angular-gantt chart in meanjs boilerplate

Tags: angularjs, gantt-chart

I'm relatively new to meanstack and i'm trying to include an angular-gantt chart in a project. i have followed all the steps according to the documentation on github but i keep getting some errors. Here's a brief overview of the steps i took.

1. Install the angular-gantt chart using

   bower install angular-gantt --save
2. I wiredep the dependencies using:

   grunt wiredep
3. I added the asset/angular-gantt.js and the asset/gant.css to the config/env/all.js file generated by yo meanjs
4. I Include the module gantt to my Angular app modules in the publlic/config.js file

5.I also ran grunt in the angular-gantt folder to build the angular-gantt.min.js and angular-gantt.js
which i realised also included angular-gantt.js.map and angular-gantt.min.js.map

6. I then included the  directive in my html
7. Finally i included the operations in my controller...

But i keep on getting the following errors

```
 TypeError: undefined is not a function
at new controller (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular-gantt/assets/angular-gantt.js:143:43)
at Object.invoke (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:4118:17)
at extend.instance (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:8312:21)
at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:7564:13
at forEach (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:347:20)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:7563:11)
at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:7824:13
at processQueue (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:12901:27)
at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:12917:27
at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:14110:28)
```

and

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [ganttTaskProgress, progress] asking for template          on: <div class="gantt-task-progress" ng-style="getCss()" ng-class="progress.classes" ng-    if="task.progress !== undefined" progress="task.progress"> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.1/$compile/multidir?p0=ganttTaskProgress&p1…task.progress%20!%3D%3D%20undefined%22%20progress%3D%22task.progress%22%3E
at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:80:12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can solve your second error. Gant has a directive called 'ganttTaskProgress' which has an attribute called 'progress'. Bootstrap has a directive called 'progress' which matches attributes. Angular therefore throws an error, as it can't apply both templates to the element. If you're not using bootstrap then have a search through your libraries and see if there's a directive called 'progress', then change its name or comment it out.

Comment: Hi, i'm angular-gantt author. This problem has been reported and is now fixed. We have prefixed every directives and services names with "gantt" to avoid those kind of problems.